# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 Can't Connect to Internet

Tags: 16.04, networking

I have a strange problem here.  I have an Ubuntu server with a VM running through a bridge on KVM, but the host machine can't connect to the internet, the VM can connect with no issues.  I've checked the my resolv.conf and it has the nameservers listed there. I even tried pinging 8.8.8.8 and I get nothing back.  I can ping other computers on my network just fine, and like I said, the VM can connect to the internet just fine.  This is a new problem that has been going on for about a day and I have searched online for answers but have had no luck.  Any suggestions about what I should do from here?

Comment: What changes were applied in the machine's config between when it could connect and when it couldn't?

Comment: I didn't change anything.  The only thing I can think of is that there was a power outage at my house, but I don't know if that would cause this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem started happening after a power outage and read sometimes it's a hardware issue.  I did a factory reset on my router and everything was back to normal.

Comment: It's not really recommended to do a factory reset as the first troubleshooting step, since that requires a lot of extra work to set up the router again.